# Create Dataframe in PySpark with a UDF GROUPED_MAP per group

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I need to train a ML model per `client_id`. I have around 100,000 clients, so the same amount of models. I use Spark with the `GROUPED_MAP` UDF to train a ML model per client in parallel.

`df.groupBy('client_id').apply(train_ml_model)`

This works very well and split every trainings job per `client_id` on a worker node.

This UDF works only for a single dataframe with a column to do your `groupBy` on. But the problem is that my data must be first queried from a warehouse per `client_id`. So there is no single dataframe yet.

In the current setup, the main dataframe must be first created but this takes many hours. There is a query like `SELECT data from datawarehouse WHERE ID IN (client_IDs)` to collect the data for all client IDs. I use `spark.read.load()` for this.

There are several options to overcome this long loading time.

**Option1:**
Is there a way to use this spark sql loading in the `GROUPED_MAP` functionality? That you do a `SELECT data FROM datawarehouse` per `client_id` in your worker nodes. And only retreive the data for that specific `client_id`

If I try that, I receive the error that the JBDC functionality cannot work on a Worker Node.

**Option2:**
This option would be that you first load your main Dataframe using the parameters `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, `numPartitions` to speed up the query. But this will take several hours as well.

Are there other options possible in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls share the full load command, are u using the .option("dbtable", "SELECT data from datawarehouse WHERE ID IN (client_IDs)") while loading. This will filter at the source and then send the required rows to spark.

Comment: I'm using that. This is the query:
`pushdown_query = f"""
(SELECT * FROM data
WHERE ID in ({client_id})) as query"""`

Here is the load:
`df_docs = (spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", driver)
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", pushdown_query)
  .option("user", username)
  .option("password", password)
  .option("databaseName", "datawarehouse")
  .option("encrypt", "true")
  .option("numPartitions", os.cpu_count())
  .option("trustServerCertificate", "true")
  .load()
)`

Comment: ok, after loading can try 2 things 1. When the data  is not skewed, you can repartition the data by client id .repartition(col('client_id')) 2. When u think some client ids can have most of the data, others can have less, when data is skewed, increase the shuffle partitions. spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",400)

Comment: @Jelmer was just curious, if your issue was resolved, came across the below article,  which might be of help to you.   https://medium.com/mercedes-benz-techinnovation-blog/increasing-apache-spark-read-performance-for-jdbc-connections-a028115e20cd